# "make" and "make install" never work

Tags: compiling, make

The commands `make` and `make install` used to install a program from an extracted tar ball never work for some reason.

The `make` command gives me the error:

```
  make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

and the `make install` command gives me the error:

```
  make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Why are these commands not executing? What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: And how are you running those commands? Give an example, for instance, cd foo/, ./make ....

Comment: no just make and make install

Comment: yes i am compiling from a tar ball...and its properly mentioned on its readme

Comment: its there...makefile.in and makefile.am....both are there

Comment: yes i have run ./configure

Comment: What package are you trying to build?

Comment: this time it is coveglobus-1.6...but this has happened many times

Comment: @Nirmik - please edit your question with all of the above and clean up by deleting your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: what's the output of configure?

Comment: run `./autogen.sh`

Comment: It's not possible to reasonably answer this given the information provided. When `make` has no targets, either `./configure` failed and should've shown an error, or the software isn't built by running `./configure` then `make` (not everything is), or the next step after `./configure` is something besides `make` (rare but possible). For a systemic problem, something is presumably broken in the system, but since you haven't given most of the information people have requested, there's no way to tell. At minimum full output of all commands during at least one build attempt would likely be needed.

Answer (score 12):

I think the problem is that you haven't got the **dependencies** for the program in question, as even though you have run `./configure` there are just the files called `makefile.in` and `makefile.am`, whereas there should be a a file called `Makefile` without an extension.

If you run `./configure` without the dependencies, it does not generate a makefile and then running make afterwards gives exactly the error you are getting:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Therefore, download the build **dependencies** for your program by looking at the readme included in the download or if the program source is in the repositories and you have enabled the source repositories, run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep program
```

After obtaining the dependencies, run `./configure` again and now make and make install should work as there will be a proper `Makefile` generated.

(You may also need to install such packages as `build-essential` which contains essential compiling tools)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes one needs to run autoreconf to generate the configure script, so use:

```
sudo apt install autoconf && autoreconf -ivf
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you build you do that as a user and then you do make install as root but as root you are in another directory.

Solution in this case: as root change directory to your build directory, then: make install

Worked for me in Debian Stretch.