# Yamcha 0.33 Make Install

Tags: software-installation, make

I am trying to install Yamcha 0.33. All steps i.e. `configure`, `make`, `make check` are successfully completed without any errors. However while executing command `make install`( sudo privileges using command `sudo -i`), it is showing following error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Any suggestions?

> > Output of ./config
> >     ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/yamcha-0.33$ ./configure
> >     checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
> >     checking whether build environment is sane... yes
> >     checking for gawk... no
> >     checking for mawk... mawk
> >     checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
> >     checking for gcc... gcc
> >     checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
> >     checking whether the C compiler works... yes
> >     checking whether we are cross compiling... no
> >     checking for suffix of executables...
> >     checking for suffix of object files... o
> >     checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
> >     checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
> >     checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
> >     checking for style of include used by make... GNU
> >     checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
> >     checking for g++... g++
> >     checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
> >     checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
> >     checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
> >     checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
> >     checking for egrep... grep -E
> >     checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
> >     checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
> >     checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> >     checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> >     checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
> >     checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
> >     checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
> >     checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
> >     checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
> >     checking whether ln -s works... yes
> >     checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
> >     checking for ANSI C header files... yes
> >     checking for sys/types.h... yes
> >     checking for sys/stat.h... yes
> >     checking for stdlib.h... yes
> >     checking for string.h... yes
> >     checking for memory.h... yes
> >     checking for strings.h... yes
> >     checking for inttypes.h... yes
> >     checking for stdint.h... yes
> >     checking for unistd.h... yes
> >     checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
> >     checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
> >     checking for dlfcn.h... yes
> >     checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
> >     checking for g77... no
> >     checking for f77... no
> >     checking for xlf... no
> >     checking for frt... no
> >     checking for pgf77... no
> >     checking for fort77... no
> >     checking for fl32... no
> >     checking for af77... no
> >     checking for f90... no
> >     checking for xlf90... no
> >     checking for pgf90... no
> >     checking for epcf90... no
> >     checking for f95... no
> >     checking for fort... no
> >     checking for xlf95... no
> >     checking for ifc... no
> >     checking for efc... no
> >     checking for pgf95... no
> >     checking for lf95... no
> >     checking for gfortran... no
> >     checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
> >     checking whether  accepts -g... no
> >     checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
> >     checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
> >     checking for objdir... .libs
> >     checking for ar... ar
> >     checking for ranlib... ranlib
> >     checking for strip... strip
> >     checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
> >     checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
> >     checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
> >     checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
> >     checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
> >     checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
> >     checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
> >     checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
> >     checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
> >     checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
> >     checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
> >     checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
> >     checking whether to build static libraries... yes
> >     configure: creating libtool
> >     appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
> >     checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
> >     checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
> >     checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
> >     checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
> >     checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
> >     checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
> >     checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
> >     checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
> >     checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
> >     appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
> >     checking for library containing strerror... none required
> >     checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
> >     checking for size_t... yes
> >     checking for string.h... (cached) yes
> >     checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
> >     checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
> >     checking fcntl.h usability... yes
> >     checking fcntl.h presence... yes
> >     checking for fcntl.h... yes
> >     checking math.h usability... yes
> >     checking math.h presence... yes
> >     checking for math.h... yes
> >     checking ctype.h usability... yes
> >     checking ctype.h presence... yes
> >     checking for ctype.h... yes
> >     checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
> >     checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
> >     checking sys/mman.h usability... yes
> >     checking sys/mman.h presence... yes
> >     checking for sys/mman.h... yes
> >     checking sys/times.h usability... yes
> >     checking sys/times.h presence... yes
> >     checking for sys/times.h... yes
> >     checking windows.h usability... no
> >     checking windows.h presence... no
> >     checking for windows.h... no
> >     checking for mmap... yes
> >     checking for pow in -lm... yes
> >     checking for main in -lstdc++... yes
> >     checking whether make is GNU Make... yes
> >     checking for perl5... no
> >     checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
> >     checking for svm_learn... /usr/local/bin/svm_learn
> >     checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports stl  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports template  (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports const_cast<> (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports static_cast<> (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports dynamic_cast<> (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports reinterpret_cast<> (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports exception handler (required)... yes
> >     checking if g++ supports namespaces (required) ... yes
> >     checking if g++ uses std namespace ... yes
> >     checking if g++ environment provides all required features... yes
> >     configure: creating ./config.status
> >     config.status: creating Makefile
> >     config.status: creating src/Makefile
> >     config.status: creating src/Makefile.bcc32
> >     config.status: creating src/Makefile.msvc
> >     config.status: creating doc/Makefile
> >     config.status: creating training/Makefile
> >     config.status: creating tests/Makefile
> >     config.status: creating libexec/Makefile
> >     config.status: creating man/Makefile
> >     config.status: creating yamcha-config
> >     config.status: creating yamcha.spec
> >     config.status: creating libexec/mkmodel
> >     config.status: creating libexec/mksvmdata
> >     config.status: creating libexec/svm_learn_wrapper
> >     config.status: creating libexec/mkparam
> >     config.status: creating libexec/showse
> >     config.status: creating libexec/zipmodel
> >     config.status: creating libexec/changeRepr.pl
> >     config.status: creating libexec/conlleval.pl
> >     config.status: creating libexec/selecttag
> >     config.status: creating perl/Makefile.PL
> >     config.status: creating ruby/extconf.rb
> >     config.status: creating python/setup.py
> >     config.status: creating config.h
> >     config.status: config.h is unchanged
> >     config.status: executing depfiles commands
> >     config.status: executing default commands
> >     ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads/yamcha-0.33$

P.S: Build-essential is also up to date.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the output of `./configure`. I have downloaded the archive and there **is** a rule for `install` in the `Makefile` after the successfully run of `./configure` .

Comment: Possible duplicate [Compiling "make" and "install" never work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182715/make-and-make-install-never-work) ?

Comment: Can you please provide more information, see my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `make` worked, then just run

```
sudo make install
```

You need administrative privileges to install software.

Comment: Hmm, no. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11954941/) error occurs, if you start a `make install` without `sudo` rights. Ok, it's another project, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: @A.B. What do you disagree with. Normally `make install` copies some files to system directories. This requires `sudo`.  But error is really weird. It should be `permission denied`. Maybe directory has been changed. It is hard to guess.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, seems to be the right answer.